# iOS: Error When accessing Async Storage: "No such file or directory"

Tags: iphone, react-native

I'm trying to access the async storage to get the array of podcasts. I add a podcast to the array and stringify it and try to persist it, and then I get the error:

> Error: Failed to write value.Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4
>   "The folder “a5a1507954e095ba66ba428410066532” doesn’t exist."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/clundberg/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F4A61A1A-9998-4C72-AD02-D6969E56990F/data/Containers/Data/Application/171D43CC-4BE5-4D64-8D30-C9582898A324/Documents/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1/a5a1507954e095ba66ba428410066532,
>   NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x604002e5c080 {Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}

Relevant code:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("@podcasts")
              .then(string => {
                console.log(string)
                const item = JSON.parse(string);
                const podcasts = [...(item ? item : []), p];
                console.log(podcasts)
                return AsyncStorage.setItem("@podcasts", JSON.stringify(podcasts));
              })
              .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Environment:

```
OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
Node: 8.11.1
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 5.6.0
Watchman: 4.9.0
Xcode: Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
Android Studio: Not Found

Packages: (wanted => installed)
react: 16.2.0 => 16.2.0
react-native: 0.53.0 => 0.53.0
```

Comment: At least share your environment information, ex: react-native version, phone info

Comment: could you add a then and catch to the set method, because the get's catch is picking the error, and it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: @Macromeda updated the post

Comment: what's the simulator's host value ? is it 127.0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage.getItem("@podcasts").then( (error,stringReturn) => {
    console.log(stringReturn);
 //the first parameter is the error checking the second one is the string you need i think
});`

Comment: Nah, it will return an error object if there's an error or the string. the error is caught in the `.catch()` line

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think it's probably erroring where you return the setItem() call. If that's true, maybe try this...

```
       AsyncStorage.getItem("@podcasts")
          .then(string => {
            console.log(string)
            const item = JSON.parse(string);
            const podcasts = [...(item ? item : []), p];
            console.log(podcasts)
            return podcasts;
          })
          .then(podcasts => AsyncStorage.setItem("@podcasts", JSON.stringify(podcasts))
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Another thought is that your simulator's AsyncStorage cache has become corrupted. The simulator stores the data on the actual file system. I'm just guessing here, but maybe the pointer to the directory has become invalid somehow. I would first try a very simple setItem() to see if it works. If it fails, then try restarting the app, clearing the cache, etc, etc. Make it all as fresh as possible.

Comment: This fails as well
AsyncStorage.setItem('test', 'test')
    .catch(error => console.log(error))

Comment: As I thought, then I believe your cache is corrupted. Reset your simulator. There's a setting to clear cache etc. There's also some scripts. I can't look them up right now as I'm on my way out the door. Hope that's enough to get you moving in the right direction though.

Comment: I finally managed to fix it. I was using react-native-fs to delete all the downloaded files, but when i had written this code I was only able to test on Android. Apparently on ios when I check the files, there's an extra directory used by async storage which was being deleted.

Comment: Ah, yes... that makes sense. Deleting the asyncstorage directory is a corruption of sorts. Glad you figured it out, and thanks for the update.